# articles tag cloud php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have tags on my articles and i wanted to make a tag cloud for it but i can't figure it out how to do that

any help would be nice

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(login_news.tag) FROM login_tags
                        LEFT JOIN login_news ON login_tags.tag_id = login_news.tag  GROUP BY tag_id
                           ");


  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){



        echo $row['name'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row['COUNT(login_news.tag)'];
        echo "<br>";

        }
```

this is as much as i could guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, add mysql alias to count(login_news.tag) by adding `AS` and called it in php as $result['AliasName']

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(login_news.tag) AS tag_count FROM login_tags
                            LEFT JOIN login_news ON login_tags.tag_id = login_news.tag  GROUP BY tag_id
                               ");


      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo $row['name'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo $row['tag_count'];
            echo "<br>";

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i did it -_-

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT tag_id, tag_name, COUNT(login_news.tag) AS tag_count FROM login_tags
    INNER JOIN login_news ON login_tags.tag_id = login_news.tag  GROUP BY tag_name
                                   ");


          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

          if($row['tag_count'] > 5){

          $fontsize = "11";

          }

          if ($row['tag_count'] > 15){

          $fontsize = "13";

          }

          if ($row['tag_count'] > 30){

          $fontsize = "15";

          }

          ?>


          <li style="font-size:<?php echo $fontsize?>!important;"><a href="/index.html?tag=<? echo $row['tag_id']; ?>" title="<? echo $row['tag_count']; ?> სიახლე"><? echo $row['tag_name']; ?></a> </li>


        <?

            }



    ?>
```